# Do I still need to bring/print e-ticket reference number if I check in on-line and print my boarding pass?

Tags: tickets, check-in, easyjet

I am flying with Easyjet and I have checked in on-line (there is no other option).  I will bring and print my boarding pass.  Is this enough, or do I still need to print and bring the e-ticket reference to the airport?

Comment: The boarding pass actually has the booking reference number on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boarding pass will be fine, nobody will check for a e-ticket. (In fact, my last few easyjet bookings have them sending me no such thing, so not quite sure how you got one).

Source: Travelled with Easyjet recently.

[Additional source, Easyjet website:](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/travel-documentation)

> ## Do I get a flight ticket from easyJet?
>
> easyJet is a ticketless airline. On completion of your booking you will receive confirmation of the flight details via email. 30 days before your flight you will be able to check in online and print your boarding pass or download it using our mobile app before going to the airport.
>
> For more information on how to check in online please visit our dedicated [online check in page.](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/online-checkin)

Comment: When I say e-ticket, I mean the booking reference, which I unterstand to be the same thing.

Comment: @gerrit My understanding from others posts on this site is that for an airline, a "ticket" is a specific internal structure/token (that Easyjet may not use) and that a booking reference was not a ticket, or a link to one, rather it was closer to a purchase transaction number, and the document containing the number largely meaningless.